Scala 3 macro Quotes: when to use apply vs copy
I'm trying to learn how to write macros with the new Scala 3 Quotes API. In this API the various AST elements usually have two methods defined to introduce them: apply and copy where copy takes a non-descript original: Tree, name: String and TypeTree and apply instead takes a Symbol which seems to contain also a name and Type.
Let's take ValDef as an example:
in QuotesImpl.scala
object ValDef extends ValDefModule:
      def apply(symbol: Symbol, rhs: Option[Term]): ValDef =
        xCheckMacroAssert(!symbol.flags.is(Flags.Method), "expected a symbol without `Method` flag set")
        withDefaultPos(tpd.ValDef(symbol.asTerm, xCheckedMacroOwners(xCheckMacroValidExpr(rhs), symbol).getOrElse(tpd.EmptyTree)))

      def copy(original: Tree)(name: String, tpt: TypeTree, rhs: Option[Term]): ValDef =
        tpd.cpy.ValDef(original)(name.toTermName, tpt, xCheckedMacroOwners(xCheckMacroValidExpr(rhs), original.symbol).getOrElse(tpd.EmptyTree))

// tpd.
def ValDef(sym: TermSymbol, rhs: LazyTree = EmptyTree, inferred: Boolean = false)(using Context): ValDef =
   ta.assignType(untpd.ValDef(sym.name, TypeTree(sym.info, inferred), rhs), sym)

// tpd.cpy.
def ValDef(tree: Tree)(name: TermName, tpt: Tree, rhs: LazyTree)(using Context): ValDef = 
    tree match {
        case tree: ValDef if (name == tree.name) && (tpt eq tree.tpt) && (rhs eq tree.unforcedRhs) => tree
        case _ => finalize(tree, untpd.ValDef(name, tpt, rhs)(sourceFile(tree)))
      }

When should I use one over the other? The copy method doesn't seem to do much that I can see; both name and type can still be changed. Is it appropriate to use copy with an existing parent-to-be of the new element that is not a ValDef or should copy only be used when I want to change a ValDef that had already existed in the same place in the tree?
Refined is another interesting case because it doesn't even have an apply method:
trait RefinedModule { this: Refined.type =>
      def copy(original: Tree)(tpt: TypeTree, refinements: List[Definition]): Refined


For clarity: Both apply and copy methods are part of the public Quotes API. I included their private implementations from QuotesImpl in my question only to discuss the possible differences between the public methods.

I would use whatever works.
Quotes API hides a lot of things so, I would:

write an Expr as '{ somecode }  and turn it to Term using asTerm
alternatively took a Type and turned it into a TypeRepr using TypeRepr.of[typeName]
then I would print tree.show(using Printer.TreeStructure)
see if apply defined withing each *Module allows creating the value in the same shape as what was printed.

If it can, then I would do just that.
There is a good chance that for a complex enough example it cannot be created, unless you are a regular compiler contributor and hack around APIs limitations, but for normal people the current answer is "don't implement functionalities requiring unavailable APIs methods". So far I saw no use cases for copy methods, probably they could be useful if someone wanted to recursively traverse and modify some Tree.

Perhaps you misunderstood my question. All of those methods exist in Quotes and the only reason I'm looking towards QuotesImpl is to figure out what they do, since Quotes is almost entirely undocumented. Both apply and copy are public API and are also used in examples everywhere.

It is really offtopic here but since you brought it up: There are many things that simply can not be done in public Quotes API as it is now. For example, you can create a class with Symbol.newClass but you can not even make it a trait because this method is lacking the needed Flags parameter that is present in QuotesImpl. Such feature request existed on Github but was denied. Who can blame people then for casting to QuotesImpl when it is the only option? But as I said, this doesn't really pertain to my question as both apply and copy are public API.

Hey, sorry, I was tired and misread your post. I updated the answer. As for the OT: I am still against doing these things, I prefer the library to not offer functionality and make me implement it by hand rather that lead me to rely on a feature that can be rug pulled from under me. Macros are most of the time just convenience utility and we can live without them. It's good to experiment with QuotesImpl in private projects, but I would be much against using any library which relies on them in the code I'd have to maintain.
